# c console api windows

Tags: c, windows, console

I have: Windows OS and installed Mingw.
I need: API to make console applications.
I only know cstdio functions, but I want more powerful interface to control input/output.

Any suggestions?

Thx.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about "more powerful interface"? It's hard to know what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has information on all of the Win32 native [console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Obviously, code that uses this API will not be portable.

Answer (score 1):

Try [NCurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Comment: I don't think ncurses will run on Windows (except in the Cygwin environment, which might or might not be of interest to the OP).  An alternative might be pdcurses: http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have used pdcurses on win xp/7 with out a problem.

Comment: You're right, of course. Apparently, NCurses on Windows does indeed require cygwin, so PDCurses makes more sense.